# Java: return previous value of field

Tags: java, class, methods, return

i start learn java and i have a little problem:

I have a class `Point`:

```
public class Point {
    int x;
    int y;

    void setX(Point point){
    x=point.x;
    }
    void setY(Point point){
    y=point.y;
    }
}
```

Now i have a task:

" change method `setX()` and `setY()` that these methods return previous values of `x` and `y`. "

Can You help me with understanding of this task? Totally dont get it.

Comment: what you have asked just implement it literally.i mean return x and y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to change from `void` to `int` return type(s) and then store the old value to return after you set it. Something like,

```
int setX(Point point) {
    int old = this.x;
    this.x = point.x;
    return old;
}

int setY(Point point) {
    int old = this.y;
    this.y = point.y;
    return old;
}
```

**or** you *might* perform the assignment in a `finally` block, and return the value in a `try` like

```
int setX(Point point) {
    try {
        return this.x;
    } finally {
        this.x = point.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. Now it's simple :)